# Is there a way to store touch screen calibration per resolution setting?

Tags: resolution, touchscreen

I have a t440s with a full HD touch-screen. For normal use it works great, so a big thank you to everyone who made this work out of the box!

The issue is that I also like to use it to "sketch" little drawings live in front of class to clarify my lectures (I'm a teacher). To do so, the built-in screen must mirror that of the projector, which includes using the latter's resolution. This varies from 800x600 up to 1280x1024 in our university.

When changing to a smaller, non-native resolution the touch screen no longer maps correctly to the picture on screen. Now, I've already discovered [`xinput-calibrator`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xinput-calibrator/) (http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xinput_calibrator/), and again it works great:

The only thing is that I have to calibrate *every time I switch resolutions*. Is there a way to make Ubuntu remember the different calibrations per resolution, and automatically switch if I change the screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script fixes the touchscreen for me when using a 4:3 resolution.

```
#!/bin/sh

# When you select a 4:3 resolution, the touchscreen and pen input aren't
# scaled correctly.  Run this script to fix it.  Each time you set the
# resolution, the matrix is reset to the identity, so we don't need a
# script that undoes this.  Adjust the device names as needed.

touchid=`xinput list | grep 'Finger touch' | sed 's/.*id=//' | sed 's/\t.*//'`
penid=`xinput list | grep 'Pen stylus' | sed 's/.*id=//' | sed 's/\t.*//'`
eraserid=`xinput list | grep 'Pen eraser' | sed 's/.*id=//' | sed 's/\t.*//'`

for d in $touchid $penid $eraserid; do
  xinput set-prop --type=float $d "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.333 0 -0.1667 0 1 0 0 0 1
done
```